# AZURE Databricks 1 Worker 1 Executor

Tags: azure, databricks

In the 'normal' Spark setup, a Worker can have many Executors.

Why in AZURE Databricks do they have 1 Worker = 1 Executor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Cloud and thus not like an HDFS cluster, things are defined differently by Databricks.

Databricks simply defines a Databricks Cluster in terms of Executors as Nodes with a single Executor for which we can say all Cores of that Worker / Machine are part of that single Executor.